# how to loop through objects in js using for/in?

Tags: javascript, object

I read that :
" The problem with a for...in loop is that it iterates through properties in the Prototype chain. When you loop through an object with the for...in loop, you need to check if the property belongs to the object. You can do this with hasOwnProperty." 
so what are the properties in the prototype chain
and how for/in iterates through them?

I tried to run the code with and without `hasOwnProperty`
but it gives the same result

```
var myCar = {
    color : "red" ,
    type  : "sedan" ,
    price : "100,000" ,
    model : "2020"
};
var prop ;
for (prop in myCar) {
    if (myCar.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        console.log(prop + " : " + myCar[prop])
    }
};

for (prop in myCar) {
        console.log(prop + " : " + myCar[prop])
};
```

the result for both codes are :
color : red
type : sedan
price : 100,000
model : 2020

Comment: All JavaScript objects have a prototype. `for (prop in obj)` enumerates through all object properties (own and inherited from prototype). In your case, the prototype doesn't have any property, so they're equivalent. The `.hasOwnProperty` is a method returning `true` only if the property is defined on current object, not inherited. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance).

Answer (score 1):

You can add properties to an object's prototype, and these will be considered properties of an object for the purposes of `for..in`. The [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method determines whether or not this property is a *direct* property of the object.

You can read more about [inheritance and the prototype chain here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

```js
function Car() {
  this.color = 'red';
  this.type = 'sedan';
  this.price = '100,000';
  this.model = '2020';
}

Car.prototype.foo = 'bar';

const car = new Car();

console.log('Props');
for (let prop in car) {
  console.log(`${prop}: ${car[prop]}`);
};

console.log('Own props');
for (let prop in car) {
  if (car.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
    console.log(`${prop}: ${car[prop]}`);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The modified code below shows what the issue is:

```
function Car(){
  this.color = "red";
  this.type  = "sedan";
  this.price = "100,000";
  this.model = "2020";
}

Car.prototype.test = function() {};

let myCar = new Car();

var prop ;
for (prop in myCar) {
    if (myCar.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        console.log(prop + " : " + myCar[prop])
    }
};

for (prop in myCar) {
        console.log(prop + " : " + myCar[prop])
};
```

Output:

```
color : red
type : sedan
price : 100,000
model : 2020
color : red
type : sedan
price : 100,000
model : 2020
test : function() {}
```

In the last iteration of the second loop, a prototype function (or a method of `Car` class) is displayed, even though it's not a property but it belongs to `Car`.

I believe that the best way to loop through an object's properties is to use `Object.keys`:

```
Object.keys(myCar).forEach(prop => {
  console.log(prop + " : " + myCar[prop]);
});
```

Comment: A nicer way in ES6, is `for (const [prop, value] of Object.entries(myCar)) {`